# jQuery : check if next file input is not empty (Selected)

Tags: jquery, html

I have 10 `<input type='checkbox'>` Checkboxes and next to them I have 10 `<input type='file'>` files

I have this **HTML**

```
<tr>
<td align="center">
<input  name="imagecheck" type="checkbox" value="0" required="required">
</td>
<td align="left">       
    <label  class="Label_Green">Photograph</label>
</td>
<td>        
    <input id=Photograph name=myFile  type="file">
</td>           
<td colspan="1"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to check, depends upon checkbox **checked**, I want user to **select file** also.

For this  I want to check [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) file input value, but I'm not able to get, what should I used

So far I tried this, I'm using my Senior's code so forget about `var $this = $(this);`

```
$("input[name=imagecheck]").each(function( index, element ) {
    var $this = $(this);    
    if( $this.is(":checked") ){
        console.log((index +1)+" : Checked");
        alert($this.next("input").prop('name') +" -:- "+$(this).next("input").prop("type"));
        alert($this.next("input").val() +" -:- "+$(this).next("input").val());
        alert($this.nextAll("input").first().prop('name') +" -:- "+$(this).nextAll("input").first().prop("name"));
        if($this.nextAll("input[type=file]").first().val() == '') {
            //tempcounter = index +1;
            $('#dialogSetter').text("Please Select the File of position ="+(index +1));
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            //tempcounter = 0;
            this.focus();
            valid= false;
            return false;
        }
    }
});//End of Checkbox Check Function
```

**UPDATED**

This is validation part for one of my `TAB` on clicking **Next Button**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT II :

Then first find your parent tr in which this is done and then find its td in which the file input is placed.

```
  $("input#imagecheck").each(function(index, element) {
    if( $(element).is(":checked") == true) {
      if($(this).closest('tr').find("td > input[type=file]").val() == '' ) {
        $('#dialogSetter').text("Please Select the File of position ="+(index +1));
          $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
          this.focus();
          valid= false;

          return false;
       }
     }
  });//End of Checkbox Check Function
```

jsfiddle to play around : https://jsfiddle.net/8wpLyxbj/

Comment: @shantaram i assume your check will be dynamic and incremental based on users selection which can be undone by user?

Comment: No, I just gave u a sample HTML, I'm already with generated HTML

Comment: @shantaram I have updated answer. In this case I have removed click event as well as your requirement is different

Comment: alert(); gives me `undefined`

Comment: should I need to use **2** `next()` , after `parent()`

Comment: can't do on `td#photo` coz, id will be different for all 10 `inputs`

Comment: @shantaram then do the way i updated in answer, accept if efforts found helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128518/discussion-between-techbreak-and-shantaram).

Comment: Thanks and warm regards for all your efforts you did

Comment: @shantaram glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Get the ancestor `tr` of each `checkbox` and find the file input in it. Then you can easily check the file input like following.

```
$("input[name=imagecheck]").each(function(index, element) {
    var $this = $(this),
        file = $this.closest('tr').find('input[type=file]')[0];

    if ($this.is(":checked") && !file.files.length) {
        alert("Please Select the File of position =" + (index + 1));
        // show your dialog here instead of alert
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks and warm regards , your `closest()` and `find()` did trick